# Error: Input past end of the file?

Tags: vbscript

I am working on VB Script and I am trying to read the txt file and sore it in a array.
I check for the number of lines and use that variable for the For loop.

I am getting an error Input past end of the file.
I am not sure how to solve this problem.

looking forward for your help.

Thank you!!

```
Dim num As Integer
'Skip lines one by one
Do While objTextFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
    objTextFile.SkipLine ' or strTemp = txsInput.ReadLine
Loop

num = objTextFile.Line - 1


Dim para()
ReDim para(num)


For i = 1 To num

    para(i) = objTextFile.ReadLine

Next
```

Comment: Similar to question and answer about "input past end of file" at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26029046/vbscript-error-input-past-end-of-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For two reasons (the second coming intp play if you fix the first):

- You have already read the file to the end. You would need to reset or reopen it.
- You are always reading 125 lines, regardless of how many lines you found.

You can read the lines and put them in the array in one go:

```
Dim para()
Dim num As Integer = 0
Do While Not objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
  ReDim Preserve para(num)
  para(num) = txsInput.ReadLine
  num = num + 1
Loop
```

Note: Arrays are zero based, and the code above places the first line at index 0. If you place the data from index 1 and up (as in the original code) you leave the first item unused, and you have to keep skipping the first item when you use the array.

#### Edit:

I see that you changed `125` to `num` in the code, that would fix the second problem.

Comment: Thank very much for your reponse. Got the output

Comment: No need to count the lines yourself. `TextStream` objects have a [`Line`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chsfhd43%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) property that holds the current line number. After having read the entire file, that is the total number of lines in the file.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: That's an option, but the use of it inside the loop wouldn't be as intuitive as the value changes in the middle of the code line where the line is read. You would use `ReDim Preserve para(txsInput.Line)` but then `para(txsInput.Line - 1) = txsInput.ReadLine`.

Comment: You could simply increase the upper boundary by 1: `ReDim Preserve para(UBound(para)+1) : para(UBound(para)) = txsInput.ReadLine`. That way redimensioning the array is largely independent of a counter variable. Also, it should be noted that dynamically resizing an array like this is bound to perform poorly, because it effectively re-creates the array over and over again, and copies all elements from the old instance to the new one. Using a `System.Collections.ArrayList` instance might be a better idea for larger arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following style code which is fast for small files:

```
Const ForReading = 1

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strList, ForReading)

strText = objTextFile.ReadAll
objTextFile.Close

arrList = Split(strText, vbCrLf)
```

Comment: That approach has the disadvantage that it will raise an error for empty files.